# Postfix IPv6 Relay access denied

Tags: postfix, ipv6

I recently set up my postfix server with both ipv4 and ipv6.  I am noticing that whenever my other server is sending the emails and it is received by the postfix server on ipv6, it is logging a "Relay access denied" and the mail gets deferred/queue.  Eventually my originating server will process the email again and gets an ipv4 from the postfix server and the mail will go through.  It seems like the postfix server is not accepting on ipv6.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Could someone please help?

Here is my postfix configuration:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_protocols = all
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
message_size_limit = 52428800
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = localhost.localdomain,
    localhost, 
mydomain = my_domain.com
myhostname = my_hostname.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 Other specific ip's
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
policy_time_limit = 3600s
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = EXP, MEDIUM, LOW, DES, 3DES, SSLv2, RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,permit
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ca.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/...crt
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = EXP, MEDIUM, LOW, DES, 3DES, SSLv2, RC4, aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/...key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_high_cipherlist =
    kEECDH:+kEECDH+SHA:kEDH:+kEDH+SHA:+kEDH+CAMELLIA:kECDH:+kECDH+SHA:kRSA:+kRSA+SHA:+kRSA+CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!SSLv2:!RC4:!MD5:!DES:!EXP:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES
tls_medium_cipherlist =
    kEECDH:+kEECDH+SHA:kEDH:+kEDH+SHA:+kEDH+CAMELLIA:kECDH:+kECDH+SHA:kRSA:+kRSA+SHA:+kRSA+CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!SSLv2:!MD5:!DES:!EXP:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smtpd_relay_restrictions` defaults to : permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 Other specific ip's
```

Is your ipv6 adress (not only `::1`) in `mynetworks` variable ?

Comment: do you mean the ipv6 of my postfix server (receiving) or the sending server?  The sending server does not have an ipv6 address.

Comment: @Mark If your other server does not have an IPv6 address, then how could the mail possibly have been received via IPv6?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Here is a message queue up in the server that is sending to the postfix server in question.
'
170B2880066     2659 Thu Oct 18 13:33:31  email@domain.com
(host smarthost.domain.com[2620:114:d000:2598::b] said: 454 4.7.1 <emailaddress@email.com>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO command)) '

Comment: @Mark That would be a good thing to add to your question. But it also means that the other server obviously does have an IPv6 address!

Comment: @MichaelHampton - DUH!!! thanks Michael. Simple fix.  Disabled the ipv6 on the machine that was talking to the postfix server.  It was not needed to communicate to the postfix server, hence I did not add it to mynetwork.

Comment: @Mark Oops! Now you have disabled IPv6, which means you won't be able to communicate with some Internet hosts, and will need to re-enable it in future. It's better to just add it to `mynetworks` as this answer suggests.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The servers I have disabled ipv6 on are my internal servers.  The postfix servers are internet facing and those still have ipv6 enabled.  Thanks again Michael, just needed someone to vet this with.